# Windows 7 Ultimate x64 / Safari / Downloads disappear

Tags: windows-7, safari, download-manager

Running Safari 4.0.5.  When I download a file, it never appears in the download folder.  If I pause the download I get the xxxxxx.xxx.download temp file to show up.  When I then resume the download, it will finish, but will never rename the file to xxxxx.xxx.

I've heard from some other posts that AV seems to have a hand in it, but I'm running clamwin av which doesn't have an in memory av process.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireFox, or download and install a download manager like [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com)